# Can't Set Width on Column in Wide Table

Tags: html, css, html-table

So my table has close to 100 columns. My problem is I can't set the width of the first column at all unless I delete some columns or delete all header text within the `<TH></TH>` tags which obviously isn't the solution

The table width is constrained by the width of the container. Is there anyway to specify the width of the first column in a very wide table at all?

I've tried `style="width:200px !important"` onto the `TH` and `TD` tags but it didn't work

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Here's a jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/16p66fxu/

Comment: Post some code or making a fiddle would be much better

Comment: It's literally a HTML table with 100 columns but will do a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/16p66fxu/

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifying exact widths in a table with that much content will never work 'right' by default, since you're only providing hints to the default table sizing algorithm. If you want precise power over the widths of all cells, just disable smart sizing:

```
table {
  table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Docs:

> Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col
>   elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in
>   subsequent rows do not affect column widths.
>
> Under the "fixed" layout method, the entire table can be rendered once
>   the first table row has been downloaded and analyzed. This can speed
>   up rendering time over the "automatic" layout method, but subsequent
>   cell content may not fit in the column widths provided. Any cell that
>   has content that overflows uses the overflow property to determine
>   whether to clip the overflow content.

As long as it's on its default of `auto` the best you can do is provide hints to the browser's automatic sizing.

[Read more on `table-layout` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout).

Comment: Thanks - that messes up my DataTables implementation unfortunately.

Comment: Not much else I can say about that - either you get smart sizing (with less control) or dumb sizing (with full control). No middle roads on this one  :)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is complicated but can be solved. As @Hamix wrote, `min-width` should be used rather than `width`. But it is not needed to set `table{width:100%;}`, in fact with wide table this will ruin the layout as the table should be allowed to be wider than the browser window, with a horizontal scroll bar. Also, with a table width of 100%, `width` works just fine. The problem is that with *oversized* tables `width` does not work on a table element.

As @Niels_Keurentjes wrote, the first row of the table determines the column width layout. I was not able to use `<col>` tags to explicitly set column widths. But an alternative would be to use a longer column header name to force a wider column, e.g. using underscores, but this would most often be an ugly hack.

Another alternative is to put a column header in a div like: `<th><div>Abcdef</div></th>` and style the div in css (or inline) with a `width:150px`.

Below are the sample files that I experimented with to get this done:

t.css:

```
.longtext{
min-width:150px;
}

table{
  /*width: 100%;*/
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,th,td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

sampletable.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="t.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <colgroup>
                <col></col>
                <col></col>
                <col></col>
                <col style="width: 200px; background-color:yellow;"></col>
                <col></col>
                <col></col>
                <col></col>
                <col></col>
                <col></col>
                <col></col>
                <col></col>
                <col></col>
                <col></col>
                <col></col>
                <col></col>
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <th>ColumnHeader</th>
                <th>ColumnHeader</th>
                <th>ColumnHeader</th>
                <th  class="longtext"><div class="longtextxx">Saying</div></th>
                <th>ColumnHeader</th>
                <th>ColumnHeader</th>
                <th>ColumnHeader</th>
                <th>ColumnHeader</th>
                <th>ColumnHeader</th>
                <th>ColumnHeader</th>
                <th>ColumnHeader</th>
                <th>ColumnHeader</th>
                <th>ColumnHeader</th>
                <th>ColumnHeader</th>
                <th>ColumnHeader</th>
                <th>ColumnHeader</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Shoot first, ask questions later</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>16</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`table { table-layout: fixed; width:100%; }`
and you needed to use the `min-width:500px` style instead of the `width` style.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/1cLwexLr/)